# How to find out what process/service initiates a network connection

Tags: windows, networking

On Windows, how do I find out what service or process initiates a network connection to a known address?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use something like GetExtendedTcpTable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know what exactly you are looking for, but [`netstat -b`](http://commandwindows.com/netstat.htm) shows processes associated with displayed ports.

Comment: Yes, provided I know when the connection is initiated and it stays connected long enough. It might be ended before netstat if even launched.